# Example of android fingerpaint in opengl?

Tags: android, opengl-es, drawing, 2d

I need to implement free form drawing in a paint app. I started with the canvas method (fingerpaint example in android) but the performance is extremely slow.

I'm now switching to openGL. If any one can point to good tutorials how I can proceed, it will help me a lot.

Comment: did you finally do it? It would help others to post your solution. Canvas is extremely slow on low quality devices.

Answer (score 1):

SpriteMethodTest from Chris Pruett is a good start to proceed:
https://github.com/mitchellhislop/apps-for-android/tree/master/SpriteMethodTest